# Microsoft Word 2010: Assigning a KEYBOARD shortcut for deleting one line of text

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

How can I assign a **keyboard shortcut to delete just *one line of text* in *Microsoft Office Word 2010*?**
A macro based solution (in Visual Basic) which could be assigned to a custom keyboard shortcut would be good too.

*Some similar examples:*

- in ***Notepad++*** I can delete (*cut*) the entire current line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- in ***NetBeans***, I can delete an entire line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- in ***Eclipse***, I can delete current line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Macro-based shortcut

OK, based on our comment discussion here's a macro based solution.

1. Create a new Macro with the following code (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, specify the name, click **Create**):

   ```vb
   Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine 
   Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend 
   Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   ```
2. Assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

   - File > Option > Customize Ribbon
   - Click on Keyboard shortcuts: **Customize** (bottom left)
   - Scroll down the **Categories** list and select **Macros**, choose your new macro
   - Press the shortcut key combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
   - Click **Assign**
   - Close > OK

And you are done. Now you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> whenever your cursor is on a line and it will perform <kbd>Home</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> - <kbd>Delete</kbd> sequence for you which will delete the line.

Hopefully, that will work for you. Cheers!

> ### (Initial) Answer that uses a mouse click
>
> If by "row" you mean a line of text
>   then the simplest way (I think) is to
>   click in the left margin on the line
>   you want to delete and hit `Del` key. 
>   If you want to avoid using the mouse
>   then I'd go for the approach suggested
>   by @*SoftArtisans*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single shortcut, but you can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> to select the entire line of text and then hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete it. If you are at the beginning of the line of text, you'll get the whole line. If not, you can press <kbd>Home</kbd> first to get to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't really solve my problem, because I wanted to avoid multiple clicks and/or pushing multiple buttons, even if I click in the middle of the line of text. :) For example, in Notepad++ I can delete the entire current line with Ctrl+L, in NetBeans, I can delete an entire line with Ctrl+E, in Eclipse, I can delete current line with Ctrl+D, etc., where it doesn't really matter where my mouse cursor is actually... so there are these simple solutions, which I look for in Word too.It really would simplify my work in huge documents.

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to the beginning of line you want to delete:

1. Open Macro under View Menu.
2. Click "start recording", give it a name, assign it to keyboard or a button. (For ex, I gave <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
3. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
4. Now stop Macro recording.

Now, whenever using a shortcut key (here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), the current line only will be deleted. It's easier and better than writing some macro code from scratch.