# Is there shortcut key to delete the line of text at the cursor, in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Visual Studio, ctrl-L deletes a line of text.

What is shortcut in Word that does that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Word 2010: Assigning a KEYBOARD shortcut for deleting one line of text](https://superuser.com/questions/298963/microsoft-word-2010-assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-deleting-one-line-of-text)

Comment: I do not know that there is. Here is how to find out: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=15896980421913